# Coalesce a set of odd numbers

Tags: cuda

I'm trying to understand coalescing global memory.
Say I'd like to load an odd set of floats to global memory.  Each thread will process a set of 3 floats.  Say these floats are A, B, and C.

```
A0,  B0,  C0
A1,  B1,  C1
A2,  B2,  C2
..          
A19, B19, C19
```

So the threads would grab the data like such:

```
Thread 0:  A0,  B0,  C0  
Thread 1:  A1,  B1,  C1  
Thread 2:  A2,  B2,  C2
..
Thread 19:  A19, B19, C19
```

First approach:
I could load 3 arrays of: `float A[20]; float B[20]; floatC[20];` I'd have to cudaMemcpy() three different times to load the data into global memory.  This approach would probably not coalesce very well.

Second approach:
A better approach would be something like:

```
struct {float A, float B, float C} dataPt;
dataPt data[20];
```

I could load the data with one cudaMemcpy(), but I'm not sure the memory access would coalesce very well.

Third approach:

```
struct {float A, float B, float C, float padding} dataPt2;
dataPt2 data2[20];
```

or

```
struct __align__(16){float A, float B, float C} dataPt3;
dataPt3 data3[20];
```

I could load the data to global memory with a single cudaMemcpy(), and the thread access to data would be coalesced.  (At the cost of wasted global memory.)

1) The 1st approach would not coalesce because each thread will probably need 3 bus cycles to load the input data.
2) The 2nd approach will coalesce for many of the threads, but there will be a few threads that will need two bus cycles to get the input data.
3) The 3rd approach will coalesce for all threads.

Is this accurate?  Is there a significant difference between the 2nd & 3rd approach?  Is there an approach the uses the 3 thread dimensions (threadIdx.x, threadIdx.y, threadIdx.z)?

Comment: *Only* your first approach will yield coalesced memory access.

Comment: I was thinking the stride between data items would prevent coalescing.  Keeping ALL the data next to each other does not help coalescing?  Does the compiler not recognize the A,B,C data as a set?  Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Coalescing has nothing to do with the compiler, it is a property of the GPU memory controller and how threads within a warp access memory. The patterns leading to coalesced access are very clearly illustrate in the appendices of the programming guide. The first case coalesces because each *thread within the same warp* will access a sequential word when reading each of `A`, `B`, and `C`.

Comment: I didn't find the Programming Guide to help much in regards to coalescing.  The Best Practices Guide V4.1 does a much better job: 6.2.1 Coalesced Access to Global Memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just amplifying on @talonmies answer.
Let's assume our kernel looks like this:

```
__global__ void kern(float *a, float *b, float *c){

  float local_a, local_b, local_c;
  int idx = threadIdx.x + (blockDim.x * blockIdx.x);

  local_a = a[idx];
  local_b = b[idx];
  local_c = c[idx];
}
```

ignoring optimizations (which would result in an empty kernel), and assuming we launch 1 block of 32 threads:

```
  kern<<<1, 32>>>(d_a, d_b, d_c);
```

Then we have 32 threads (1 warp) executing in lock-step.  That means each thread will process the following kernel code line:

```
  local_a = a[idx];
```

at exactly the same time.  The definition of a coalesced load (from global memory) is when a warp loads a sequence of data items that are all within a single 128-byte aligned boundary in global memory (for CC 2.0 devices).  A perfectly coalesced load with 100% bandwidth utilization implies that each thread is using one unique 32 bit quantity within that 128 byte aligned region.  If thread zero loads a[0], thread 1 loads a[1], etc, that may be a typical example of a coalesced load.

So in your first case, since the a[] array is all contiguous and aligned, and a[0..31] fit within a 128 byte aligned region in global memory, we get a coalesced load.  thread 0 reads a[0], thread 1 reads a[1] etc.

In the second case, a[0] is not contiguous with a[1], and furthermore the elements a[0..31] (which are all loaded at the same code line) do not fit within a 128 byte aligned sequence in global memory.  I'm going to let you parse what happens in your third case, but suffice it to say that like the second case, the elements a[0..31] are niether contiguous nor contained within a single 128 byte aligned region in global memory.  While it's not necessary to have data items that are contiguous to achieve some level of coalescing, a 100% bandwidth utilization ("perfectly") coalesced load from a 32 thread warp implies that each thread is using a unique 32bit item, all of which are contiguous and contained within a single 128-byte aligned sequence in global memory.

A handy mental model is to contrast an Arrary of Structures (AoS) (which corresponds to your cases 2 and 3) and a Structure of Arrays (SoA), which is essentially your first case.  SoA's usually present better possibilities for coalescing than AoS's. From the [nvidia webinar page](http://developer.nvidia.com/gpu-computing-webinars)  you may find [this presentation](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/CUDA/training/cuda_webinars_GlobalMemory.pdf) interesting, especially slides 11-22 or so.

Answer (score 0):

Some other relevant info from the Best Practices Guide:

> For devices of compute capability 2.x, the requirements can be
>   summarized quite easily: the concurrent accesses of the threads of a
>   warp will coalesce into a number of transactions equal to the number
>   of cache lines necessary to service all of the threads of the warp. By
>   default, all accesses are cached through L1, which as 128-byte lines.
>   For scattered access patterns, to reduce overfetch, it can sometimes
>   be useful to cache only in L2, which caches shorter 32-byte segments
>   (see the CUDA C Programming Guide).

The compiler flag: `-Xptxas -dlcm=cg`  will disable L1 cache.  i.e. Use only L2, for poorly coalesced data.